# Why does AI CS6's menu version of Pathfinder > Divide do nothing while the panel version works?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pathfinder, illustrator-cs6

In Adobe Illustrator CS6, there is a menu item, Effect > Pathfinder > Divide, which I expect should take two overlaying vector shapes and divide one on the line segments of the other.  It fails.  On the other hand, if I use the Pathfinder panel and click on the Divide button, it does exactly that.  Can someone explain the difference and how to access the same thing via the file menu or keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're running into a targeting issue. The effect needs to be applied to a container, not individual paths. If the paths are in a group selecting the group automatically targets the group. You can see this in the Layers panel where there's a circle on the right side to indicate targeting and effects.

In the image below I've selected all. The group automatically has the double ring to indicate it's targeted but the "loose" objects in the layer below are targeted individually.

[image]
You can target the layer by clicking in its targeting circle before applying the effect and it will affect everything inside layer.

Once you apply an effect the circle will have a little bump in it to indicate this. To view/edit the effect click on the bump and open the Appearance panel. You can remove effects by dragging the bump to the trash can in the Layers panel.